# AutoMapper select default implementation for ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, collections, automapper

When AutoMapper maps instance of this class, it maps `ICollection<T>` to `List<T>`. It should be `HashSet<T>`. How can I select default implementation for `ICollection<T>`?

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bar = new HashSet<int>();
        Bar2 = new HashSet<string>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<int> Bar { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<string> Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Class instance has properties of type `HashSet<T>` assigned in constructor.

Comment: Is the source collection you are mapping from also a `HashSet<T>`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, yep!

Comment: If you need the properties to be HashSet then maybe you should type them as such?

Comment: @GertArnold, in my case the `Foo` class is the Entity Framework Core class generated by framework. The best solution is to change default AutoMapper behavior.